# DataFormatString doesn't work for DateTime field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, html-helper

In the model I have this property:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EndDate;
```

In the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate)
```

And it shows up in this format: 2013.10.15. 13:19:05

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try `@Html.TextBoxFor`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @Value = Model.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"), @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Change your string format as your need !

Answer (score 0):

I just have learned something in the hard way :)

There was several not expected behaviour because the field I tried to edit in the view was not a property, but a public data member... I thought everything except this.